# Swift giving me error at function with return of an enum

Tags: swift, enums

Why isn't this working?

```
enum SwitchStatus {
    case on
    case off
}

var switchStatus: SwitchStatus = .off

func flipSwitch() -> SwitchStatus {
    return !switchStatus
}
```

I get this error at `return !switchStatus`:

> Cannot convert value of type 'SwitchStatus' to expected argument type 'Bool'

Why does it expect `Bool` if I say return `SwitchStatus`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is the “Logical NOT” operator and takes a `Bool` argument, therefore 
the compiler complains already on the `!switchStatus` expression.

You could extend `!` to `SwitchStatus` arguments by defining a

```
prefix func !(arg: SwitchStatus) -> SwitchStatus
```

function, but what I would actually do is to define a `flip()` method,
similar to the `toggle()` method that has been [added to `Bool` in Swift 4.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0199-bool-toggle.md):

```
enum SwitchStatus {
    case on
    case off

    mutating func flip() {
        switch self {
        case .on: self = .off
        case .off: self = .on
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
var switchStatus: SwitchStatus = .on

switchStatus.flip() // Switch if off ...
switchStatus.flip() // ... and on again.
```

Comment: **self = self == .on ? .off : .on**

Comment: @Sh_Khan: Yes, but actually I prefer the switch statement, even if it is some more keystrokes: Apart from the nice symmetry, the compiler will complain if a third case is (accidentally) added later to the enumeration, instead of (silently) treating any additional case like `.off`.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
return switchStatus == .on ? .off : .on
```

Answer (score 0):

Sh_Khan has the right answer. And you probably want to have that function be part of the enum

```
enum SwitchStatus {
    case on
    case off

    func flipSwitch() -> SwitchStatus {
        return self == .on ? .off : .on
    }
}
```